# JPA Query for filtering nested entity when fetching parent entity

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, jpql

I have a Spring Boot project. These are my 3 classes that represent the User, Group, and Membership(@ManyToMany relation between the user and the group with custom table) entities:

User.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Membership> membership;
}
```

Group.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "group",
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Set<Membership> members;
}
```

Membership.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Membership extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User member;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;
```

And the BaseEntity that I am extending on the 3 classes has a property deleted of type boolean that is used for soft deletion.

The problem I have is this:

- When I remove a user from a group I get the membership row that represented the relationship between the user and the group and set the deleted flag to true. But when all of the users are removed from the group then the query that I have does not return that group anymore, but I want to be able to still see the group even though all of the members have been removed. This is the query I use:

```
@Query("""
        SELECT DISTINCT g FROM Group g
        LEFT JOIN FETCH g.members m
        WHERE m.deleted = false OR m IS NULL
        """)
    Set<Group> findAllGroupsWithNonDeletedMembers(Sort sort);
```

- I tried with different queries but I could not make it work, and the same problem goes from the user side, if I remove the user from all the groups he is a part of then that user is no longer returned. This is the query I use for fetching the users:

```
@Query("""
       SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u
       LEFT JOIN u.membership m ON m.deleted = true
       """)
    List<User> findAllUsersWithNonDeletedMemberships();
```

So my question is, what kind of query should I write so that I can accomplish the result I want?
Thanks.